# How to count the number of recurring character repetitions in a char list?

Tags: ocaml

My goal is to take a char list like:

```ml
['a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'a'; 'd'; 'd'; 'd'; 'd']
```

Count the number of repeated characters and transform it into a (int * char) list like this:

```ml
[(5, 'a'); (3, 'b'); (1, 'a'); (4, 'd')]
```

I am completely lost and also am very very new to OCaml. Here is the code I have rn:

```ml
let to_run_length (lst : char list) : (int * char) list =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> 
    let count = int 0 in
    while t <> [] do
      if h = t then
        count := count + 1;
    done;
```

I am struggling on how to check the list like you would an array in C or Python. I am not allowed to use fold functions or map or anything like that.

Edit: Updated code, yielding an exception on `List.nth`:

```
let rec to_run_length (lst : char list) : (int * char) list =
  let n = ref 0 in
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> 
    if h = List.nth t 0 then n := !n + 1 ;
              (!n, h) :: to_run_length t ;;
```

Edit: Added nested match resulting in a function that doesn't work... but no errors!

```
let rec to_run_length (lst : char list) : (int * char) list =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> 
    match to_run_length t with
    | [] -> []
    | (n, c) :: tail -> 
      if h <> c then to_run_length t
      else (n + 1, c) :: tail ;;
```

Final Edit: Finally got the code running perfect!

```
let rec to_run_length (lst : char list) : (int * char) list =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> 
    match to_run_length t with
    | (n, c) :: tail when h = c -> (n + 1, h) :: tail
    | tail -> (1, h) :: tail ;;
```

Comment: Please don't change you question in ways that invalidate existing answers. I've changed your question to be additive instead of changing existing code, although technically you ought to ask a separate question when you have an entirely different problem.

Comment: Sorry about that! I am new to the stack overflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to answer your question is to point out that a list in OCaml isn't like an array in C or Python. There is no (constant-time) way to index an OCaml list like you can an array.

If you want to code in an imperative style, you can treat an OCaml list like a *list* in C, i.e., a linked structure that can be traversed in one direction from beginning to end.

To make this work you would indeed have a `while` statement that continues only as long as the list is non-empty. At each step you examine the head of the list and update your output accordingly. Then replace the list with the tail of the list.

For this you would want to use references for holding the input and output. (As a side comment, where you have `int 0` you almost certainly wanted `ref 0`. I.e., you want to use a reference. There is no predefined OCaml function or operator named `int`.)

However, the usual reason to study OCaml is to learn functional style. In that case you should be thinking of a recursive function that will compute the value you want.

For that you need a base case and a way to reduce a non-base case to a smaller case that can be solved recursively. A pretty good base case is an empty list. The desired output for this input is (presumably) also an empty list.

Now assume (by recursion hypothesis) you have a function that works, and you are given a non-empty list. You can call your function on the tail of the list, and it (by hypothesis) gives you a run-length encoded version of the tail. What do you need to do to this result to add one more character to the front? That's what you would have to figure out.

**Update**

Your code is getting closer, as you say.

You need to ask yourself how to add a new character to the beginning of the encoded value. In your code you have this, for example:

```
. . .
match to_run_length t with
| [] -> []
. . .
```

This says to return an empty encoding if the tail is empty. But that doesn't make sense. You know for a fact that there's a character in the input (namely, `h`). You should be returning some kind of result that includes `h`.

In general if the returned list starts with `h`, you want to add 1 to the count of the first group. Otherwise you want to add a new group to the front of the returned list.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I have been working to develop a recursive function that would solve this. I have updated my question with the new code. I am getting Exception: Failure "nth"

Comment: This has some of the right ideas, but doesn't get you all the way. For one thing, there are a few cases involved in handling the return from the recursive call. First, it might not start with the same character as `h` (the head of the list). Second, it might in fact start with the same character as `h`. Third (if not the same as the first case) it might be empty. You should perhaps think of matching the return value against some patterns to separate out these cases.

Comment: As another comment, don't use `List.nth`. As I said, lists can't be indexed in constant time. So you shouldn't think of them as being like arrays. You don't need to index any lists to code up a good solution.

Comment: Would a nested match loop be useful here then? Another thought of mine was to do something like this:
`h ::t ->
  match to_run_length with
  ....
` Then have the 3 cases you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this nested match is exactly what I was talking about. But it's wouldn't be a loop per se. If you solve recursively there will be no loops.

Comment: I have another addition to the code. I think it is getting closer, but am a little confused on how to actually create the output needed. Let me know what you think about the update!

Comment: I have gotten to a working edition of the code! Although, I did have some help from a friend of mine specifically on the `when` operator. I did not know you could use it in such a way!

Answer (score 0):

Note that your solution:

> ```
> let rec to_run_length (lst : char list) : (int * char) list =
>   match lst with
>   | [] -> []
>   | h :: t -> 
>     match to_run_length t with
>     | (n, c) :: tail when h = c -> (n + 1, h) :: tail
>     | tail -> (1, h) :: tail
> ```

Leaves room for improvement. Notably, it is not tail-recursive, and for large lists, a stack overflow will occur.

`List.fold_left` provides a nice way of overcoming this as it is naturally tail-recursive. Because the fold will build up our list in reverse order, we'll be able to grab the most recent character added to the result by pattern-matching on the accumulator.

We then just have to reverse that accumulator to get the desired result.

```
let to_run_length lst =
  lst
  |> List.fold_left 
       (fun i x -> 
          match i with 
          | (count, ch)::t when x = ch -> (count+1, ch)::t
          | _ -> (1, x)::i)
       [] 
  |> List.rev
```